# Removing references and relativizing references in an HTML hierarchy

Tags: html, perl, awk, sed

I have a web site which was created in 1994, hasn't been well maintained, contains several thousand individual files.  There are over 3800 absolute URL references in the files, and they all have to be removed or eliminated in order to move the site to a new host.

About half the references are meta references to the now defunct icra site, so those can just be discarded wholesale.  I can identify them with a simple pipeline, e.g.:

```
cat foo.html|grep meta|grep icra
```

But now I have to get rid of the line.  I tried making this pipeline an argument in sed and then using sed to delete the line, but it was awkward and didn't work properly.

Once that part is done, it would be nice to have a way to relativize all the links, e.g., if I had a file two levels down in the hierarchy with a reference to 
http://olddomain.org/dir1/dir2/dir3/foo.html, that would get changed to ../../dir1/dir2/dir3/foo.html

It wouldn't bother me if I wound up having references that went up and then back down exactly the same directories - I could fix those slowly and by hand, as necessary.

Thanks

Comment: @serenesat: Here's one for you

Comment: The complexity of what you're talking about is probably not something you want to do with just sed.  You're talking about parsing and modifying HTML, which is structured data.  I would get an actual programming language like Perl or Python or Ruby and write a program to do it.

Comment: This isn't a specific question, and in this case it's really more of a project. A 22-year-old web site really needs a rewrite, but it is a fair first step to make what you already have work under a new scheme. Even so I have to vote to close your question as being *too broad*

Comment: @AndyLester: I know what you mean, but implying that awk, sed, bash etc. aren't *"actual programming languages"* is asking for trouble!

Comment: This breaks site rules, but I will do some of this for you at no cost. Contact me at nugeceslad@thraml.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the site is still alive, you can use `wget --convert-links` to copy the site and at the end convert internal links to relative.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very nice tool.  I was able to solve the problem by fixing 98% of the files with some simple scripts, and then did the rest by hand, but this is a nice thing to know about.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML files are well structured enough that the element you need to remove is on a single line and no other elements are on that line, then this is pretty easy.

```
perl -i -ne 'print unless /meta/ && /irca/' foo.html
```

This rewrites `foo.html` in place, removing any lines that contain both strings `"meta"` and `"irca"`.

Comment: Thanks, I did something very similar to this for most of the references.